# How to solve 422 error in Lumen react Post request?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I am new in Lumen also in React, so i don't know what is going wrong with my code it return the error like below, I am using axios library. **It works fine in postman**

[image]

**Here is my react code**

```
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        // Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register', data).then(res => {
        //     console.log(res);
        // })

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
```

**Lumen Code**

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $name = $request->input('name');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $hashPassword = Hash::make($password);

        $user = User::create([
            'email' => $email,
            'name' => $name,
            'password' => $hashPassword
        ]);

        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'user_id' => $user->id], 201);
    }
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: this is because your`validation` is not fulfilled, so lumen throwing `422` error code

Comment: How can i solve this error @Vibha Chosla

Comment: make sure that your `$request` data are in form which are you looking for,try to `dd($request)` in your controller before validating it, and check all parameters are set or not